# If $X_1, X_2, \ldots \sim [0,1]$ are iid and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$, then $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge in probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have that $X_1, X_2, \ldots \sim [0,1]$ (no specified distribution) are iid and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$, then by the Central Limit Theorem we have that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution. How can we show that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not converge in probability to $N(0,1)$?

Comment: This question has flawed statements.

Comment: $(S_n-nE[X])/\sqrt{nVar(X)}$ converges to Gaussian $N(0,1)$ in distribution by CLT.  $S_n/n$ converges to $E[X]$ with prob 1 (and hence in probability) by LLN.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your response! Could you tell me which statements are flawed?

Comment: The very ones that I clarified in my second comment. For example, what if $X_n$ is uniform over $[1/2, 1]$ for all $n$? This satisfies your assumption but clearly $S_n/\sqrt{n} \geq (n/2)/\sqrt{n} \rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Michael I think my question was why $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ doesn't converge in probability to $N(0,1)$, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Try computing the mean of $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ and you will see it does not even converge in distribution to anything, except for the trivial case when $E[X_i]=0$.